# Cross browser display issues at different sizes in firefox and chrome (only mobile)

Tags: css, cross-browser, responsive

My website is displaying differently in mobile versions of Chrome and Firefox. I got to know that Chrome uses webkit and Firefox uses Gecko, so we can't expect exact same site in both. But there are some things which i want to display same in both.

I am not looking for pixel-perfect display in both, i just want to fix some small things. I read about CSS reset but that doesn't seems like solution for my problem.

I know i am doing something terribly wrong here, but i am not able to figure it out. Please read the full post i have tried my best to explain the full issue. i am badly stuck here i did some research but i have no idea of what's going wrong. Thanks in advance

This is my website (Note: colors are added for debugging purposes)
https://gallant-bell-95a482.netlify.app/#

Note: the issue is not in laptop screen (even selecting mobile screen from laptop browser isn't reproducing the issue for me).

I will post the screenshots of website at different system font-sizes take a look.

**How i want it?**

1. When user increases font size of mobile i don't want the size of icons to be increased and popping out of the box which is happening in firefox (screenshots below).
2. When user increases the font size i want the font size of text to be increased (which is not happening in chrome).

Note: i have used pixels for specifying everything (margin, padding, width,...) i even changed font-size from rem to px to solve this issue.

[image: Icon width]

(It appears like Firefox is increasing the value of 1px when the system font size is increased because i am not using any relative units like em , rem)

My mobile is redmi note 5.

(Note: red search bar will show up on clicking the search icon in mobile display)

**font-size: small**

At small font size which is supposed to be the default in mobile both chrome and firefox render as expected.

chrome
[image: Chrome small]

firefox
[image: Firefox small]

font-size: medium

At medium font size chrome still keeps the same site (even font size of the text displayed is same). But we can see firefox has already started messing up the layout, eg: red search bar is no more centered. Also font size of text increased on firefox but not on chrome.

chrome

[image: Chrome Medium]

firefox
[image: Firefox medium]

font-size: large

At large font size chrome stil keeps everything same. But Firefox totolly messes up the layout, even SVG icons started popping out of the box.

chrome
[image: Chrome Large]

firefox  **important**
[image: Firefox large]

Example from Instagram's layout at large font-size.

Chrome Instagram font-size: large
[image: Chrome Instagram]

Firefox Instagram
[image: Firefox Instagram]

We can see that even though some parts of layout appears to be distorted in Instagram icons are not popping out.

Code:

It is a react project there are lot of files. I am only pasting CSS and JS files with issues (i can share my Github repo if required)

[index.css](https://pastebin.com/X17s8uas) - even though i have used relative usits in the template it is overriden by px in almost everywhere.

[Navbar.js](https://pastebin.com/HKAtXrbH)

[Navbar.css](https://pastebin.com/EYdKyj0S)

```
Code
```